# Lip Recognition in Java Android

Tags: face-detection

I would like to be able to recognize lips in a camera app on Android. I was able to find center of a mouth but I am not sure how to do it with lips. I would like to have several points on lips which are recognized. I was thinking of using opencv, but Android is all java.

! [the app should recognize just the lips for example which are highlighted with lipstick as here] (http://s3.amazonaws.com/rapgenius/red-lips_1024x768_29987.jpg)

Any ideas?

Thanks!!!!

-epsilon

Answer (score 0):

it has an android edition:

Check this code.

http://www.technolabsz.com/2012/03/opencv-facenosemoutheye-concurrent.html